# Which functoid(s) allow use of a DataTable, returned from an external assembly, in a BizTalk map?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I figured I'd be able to use an Index functoid but it doesn't seem to like my first parameter (the scripting functoid that calls the external assembly) - a red X in place of the usual green check mark.

The thing that makes me think it's possible, is that the Index functoid doesn't give me an error at all - it compiles and deploys with no complaints. The problem is that the mapping never takes place, I get a catastrophic failure (IMO) because it doesn't even return an error.

So, any way to use an external assembly that returns a DataTabe/DataRow/DataSet in a BizTalk map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this does not address your question entirely but I always think that any calls to external dependencies should be done before the mapping stage, and the results stored in a message.

The map would have multiple input schemas, one of which could be a DataRow (modelled on the ADO DataRow).

Then when you call the transform you pass all the messages in which are needed to do the transform. This makes it much easier to isolate your genuine mapping failures from other failures.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
[Code Behind BizTalk Functoids](http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2008/02/20/Understanding+The+BizTalk+Mapper+Part+11+Advanced+Functoids.aspx)

You may be able to get some insight into how the mapper does its thing.